2-Party FSS with Additive Secret Sharing in a Malicious Setting
Suppose that we have two computing parties performing linear operations with additive Secret Sharing (SS) and non-linear functions (e.g., comparisons) with Function Secret Sharing (FSS); now we want it to be secure in the presence of malicious adversaries in the honest majority setting.
I am quite new to this field and searching for resources or solutions on these research questions:

I understood that 3PC is beneficial particularly for an honest majority setting. I am in doubt which approach can be easier or more practical in this scenario (2PC or 3PC)?
I have read some papers that majority of them are referring to Replicated Secret Sharing (RSS), are we taking advantage for this to do linear operations?
Next and more importantly, I realize based on some papers (e.g., here) that FSS in malicious setting cannot be applied for 2PC. I am not sure and still looking for some proofs.

I appreciate any assistance.
